# Change Pay button with image on checkout based on Woocommerce chosen payment method

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, payment-gateway, hook-woocommerce

Through this function I can change the text on the pay button.
I would like to insert a small image instead.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_available_payment_gateways', 'woocommerce_available_payment_gateways' );
function woocommerce_available_payment_gateways( $available_gateways ) {
    if (! is_checkout() ) return $available_gateways;  // stop doing anything if we're not on checkout page.
    if (array_key_exists('paypal_express',$available_gateways)) {
        // Gateway ID for Paypal is 'paypal'. 
         $available_gateways['paypal_express']->order_button_text = __( 'PAY', 'woocommerce' );

    }
    return $available_gateways;
}
```

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As in the frontend the button text will be changed by using `.text()` function of jQuery, adding html like img tag won't work here.

I suggest instead though to you use javascript with jQuery. It should be something like this:

```
$( document.body ).on( 'payment_method_selected', function(){
    var selectedPaymentMethod = $( '.woocommerce-checkout input[name="payment_method"]:checked' ).attr( 'id' );
    $( '#place_order' ).find('.payment-icon');
    $( '#place_order' ).prepend('<span class="payment-icon '+ selectedPaymentMethod +'"></span>'); // or any element like from font-awesome.
});
$( document.body ).trigger( 'payment_method_selected' ); // this will trigger on page load, act as initialize the icon.
```

The script above will add a `span` tag with classes `payment-icon` and an ID of the selected payment method. You can then use css to add your icon as background in this span.

Comment: Thanks mr. Reigel. I understood how the function and variables work, but I have not understood how to insert or integrate them in my function, thanks again for the help ...